# Extract filename from path and assign it to a variable is not working in shell script

Tags: shell, unix

When I tried to print the file name from path the below code working properly,

```
echo "${FILE_PATH##*/}"
```

But when I tried to assign this file name to a variable as shown below then its throwing  command not found in unix.

```
var = "${FILE_PATH##*/}"
```

Please help me what I am doing wrong here in a shell script file.

Comment: You can't have spaces between variable assignments

Comment: Thank you very much . Its working fine . I am new to shell script.

Comment: And, there is NO parameter expansion/substring removal in `sh`, only `bash`. If it is `bash`, then yes, just get rid of the spaces around `=`.

Comment: Thanks David . It is bash.

Comment: By the way, POSIX `sh` does support prefix removal (`${parameter##[word]}`).  See:  [Parameter Expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02)